# How to set the number of moved files?

Tags: terminal

I'm moving `png` files from `source/` to `dest/` with this:

`mv /source/*.png /dest/`

How can I change that command so I only move 10 `png` files?

Comment: Specify the correct file name pattern, maybe? What about `ls | head -10`?

Comment: @U.Windl see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: @cas **I** know how to do that correctly, but I wanted the OP to explain a bit more what he *really* wants to do, or what the real problem is.

Comment: so why suggest parsing ls? that's just irresponsible, especially if you claim to know better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in Zsh with a [glob qualifier](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers):

```
mv /source/*.png([1,10]) /dest/
```

Moves the first 10 ones in alphabetic order. You can pick a different order using the `o`/`O`/`n` qualifiers. For instance:

```
mv /source/*.png(OL[1,10]) /dest/
```

Would move the 10 largest ones.

An optimised version that selects the first 10 matches without bothering to sort can be done with the `Y` qualifier:

```
mv /source/*.png(Y10) /dest/
```

Answer (score 4):

POSIXly, that could be done with:

```
set -- /source/*.png
[ "$#" -le 10 ] || shift "$(( $# - 10 ))"
mv -- "$@" /dest/
```

Which would move the 10 last ones in alphabetic order.

Note that it excludes hidden ones and if there's no match, it would attempt to move a file called `/source/*.png` and likely fail.

Answer (score -1):

`ls /source/*.png | head -n10 | xargs -I{} mv {} /dest/`

Comment: This is only safe if you're using a recent version of GNU `ls` with the `--zero` option, combined with `head -z -n 10`, and `xargs -0r ...`.  And, since everything else relies on GNU versions, you may as well use GNU `mv`'s `-t` option too.   `ls --zero /source/*.png | head -z -n 10 | xargs -0r mv -t dest/`.   Even so, it's still better to use `find`: `find /source -maxdepth 1 -name '*.png' -print0 | head -z -n 10 | xargs -0r mv -t dest/`.

Comment: @cas so using `ls --zero` avoids the problem of `never parse ls`? I have no idea about `--zero` and how that works but with your example I understood better.

Comment: @EdgarMagallon `--zero` is fairly new for GNU ls (first added as --null in July 2021, renamed to --zero a few days later.  BTW, according to the changelog, *"--zero also implies -1, -N, --color=none, --show-control-chars"*).  I wouldn't say "avoids the problem" - won't help at all for parsing metadata out of `ls -l` (that's what `stat` is for, anyway) but should be OK for just generating a list of NUL-separated files to pipe into other programs or read into an array with `mapfile`.  Personally, I'll stick with using `find`, although the convenience of ls's sorting capabilities might be useful.

Comment: @cas thanks for the explanation! That's very clear and useful. I will take a look at the manuals too. As you said it'll be better keep using `find` or `for in /somepath` too